# Is there a way to make my objects "update" their formula based variables?

Tags: java, variables, arraylist

I have a method for creating "spirit" objects in my game.  I create an instance of the spirit class, and then call a method for whichever spirit I want to make.  Example:

```
public void risp(){
species = "Risp";
eletype = "plant";
baseattack=4; basespeed=4; baseevasion=5; basearmor=2; basemagres=3; basehealth = 13+2*strength; basemana = 13+intelligence;
attack = (int) (baseattack+.2*4*strength+strength); speed = (int) (basespeed+4*.2*dexterity); health = 13+2*strength; mana = 13+intelligence; 

armor = (int) (basearmor+2*.2*strength); armit = 0; magres = (int) (basemagres+.2*3*intelligence); mrmit = 0; evasion = (int) (dexterity+.25*5*baseevasion); cooperation = 12; accuracy = 10+dexterity;           
fire = 5; water = 35; air = 35; ice = 25; mud = 40; rock = 20; toxic = 25; energy = 10; dark = 15; death = 15; light = 20; plant = 0; psychic = 5;
ability1 = "prick"; ability2 = "photosynethesize"; ability3 = "regrowth"; ability4 = "None Equipped";
spiritimage = new Image(risptexture);
spiritimage2 = new Image(risptexture);
spiritxp = 0; spiritlvl = 1;

}
```

The problem is, in my noobness, I put formulas for some of the values expecting the variables would update whenever the object was used.  This does not seem to be the case, and thinking about it, it makes sense that it just uses whatever the value was initialized to be.

So, when I have leveled up my "risp", and made it's base attack much higher, say, 10 - it doesn't care.  Risp still has it's initial attack value, which comes out to 6, when I want it should be 12.

The object I create that represents risp is stored in an arraylist that holds my "spirit characters".

I do not know how to update my variables that are based on a formula like attack, speed, health, etc.

I know that I could write code that does

```
if(spirit.species = "Risp") { 
attack = (int) (baseattack+.2*4*strength+strength);
```

as well as the other variables, and then call that any time I change risps's base values.  But that would be.. so much typing.  I have a lot of spirits.  I want to try to avoid that.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Use methods and call those methods.

Comment: When asking a question, please make it a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, complete, verifiable example) and use proper whitespace and indentation in your code so it is easier to read. There is a lot of arbitrary information here that is not relevant to the question. One of the fields in `risp` not behaving how you want it to would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in Java, you could always make different characters be of different classes, and make getters perform calculations for current stats.

For example:

```
public class Risp {
    private int baseattack, basespeed; // ... and so on
    // also have a constructor that sets all base stats

    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String getSpecies() {
        return "Risp";
    }
    public int getAttack() {
        return (int) (baseattack+.2*4*strength+strength);
    }
    // remaining setters & getters omitted
}
```

Then whenever you need to use those values:

```
Risp risp = new Risp();
risp.getAttack(); // Returns attack with base stats
risp.setStrength(120);
risp.getAttack(); // Returns attack with base stats, but w/ strength 120
```